# Eclipse Comment generator plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, comments

I was wondering if there was a comment generator instead of doing `Shift+Alt+j` for each element is there a way for doing it for the whole project at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JautoDoc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jautodoc/) is one such plugin and it does a very decent job too.

Comment: ok the update site works fine but if I download the files it doesn't